# How to reload a page after click event vb.aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm updating a form's values that come from a code-behind update table in SQL. How can I call the form again or refresh it in order to see the changes of the code-behind update?

```
cn.Open()
    Dim nusa3 As String = "update nfl set e1ve2='" & uno & "', e2ve1='" & dos & "',e3ve4='" & tres & "',e4ve3='" & cuatro & "',e5ve6='" & cinco & "',e6ve5='" & seis & "',e7ve8='" & siete & "',e8ve7='" & ocho & "',e9ve10='" & nueve & "',e10ve9='" & diez & "',e11ve12='" & once & "',e12ve11='" & doce & "',e13ve14='" & trece & "',e14ve13='" & catorce & "',e15ve16='" & quince & "',e16ve15='" & dieciseis & "',e17ve18='" & diecisiete & "',e18ve17='" & dieciocho & "',e19ve20='" & diecinueve & "',e20ve19='" & veinte & "',e21ve22='" & veintiuno & "',e22ve21='" & veintidos & "',e23ve24='" & veintitres & "',e24ve23='" & veinticuatro & "',e25ve26='" & veinticinco & "',e26ve25='" & veintiseis & "',e27ve28='" & veintisiete & "',e28ve27='" & veintiocho & "',e29ve30='" & veintinueve & "',e30ve29='" & treinta & "',e31ve32='" & treintayuno & "',e32ve31='" & treintaydos & "'  where userid=" & ide & ""
    Dim cmd3 As New OleDbCommand(nusa3, cn)
        cmd3.ExecuteScalar()
        cn.Close()

    Response.Redirect("detalles.aspx")
```

Comment: what you should do is very context-dependent. We'd need to see some relevant code to understand how your page is structured.

Comment: I need to refresh the page or reload it

Comment: That query affect certain inputboxes in the form, how to reflect the changes based on the new database values!

Comment: Two side issues:  1) .ExecuteScalar() is the wrong method for an UPDATE. ExecuteNonQuery is the right method. UPDATEs do not return values, whereas ExecuteScalar expects a return value. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx
2) Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks because you are naively building the query by joining strings together. You need to use SQL Parameters to protect your code from malicious input which could steal, corrupt or destroy your data. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for a discussion and some examples

Comment: Back to the main point. It looks like you are already redirecting to another page when the query finishes. So, assuming the query succeeds, it should already refresh the data. Not sure what the issue is. Is this code you've shown already part of "detalles.aspx", or another page? Perhaps you need to read about the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle and read some simple examples of updating form data and re-displaying it, there are dozens of tutorials online.

Comment: not redirect to another page its the same page i need to reload or something that can reflect the changes

Comment: If you show us how you are displaying the data in the first place we might be able to help. Perhaps you need to re-bind your data source? Without seeing the code you used to display your data it's impossible to give a proper answer. Although it's hard to see why a redirect wouldn't do the job, albeit inefficiently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A reload can be done via Ajax.
jQuery is a good framework to do that, you do not need to reload the entire page.
For that you need a second page which calls the data from you database. The content of that page you load into a DOM element of you choice.

Please have a look at the jQuery doc http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    function loaddata() {
         var pathtosecondpage = "ajax/test.html";

         $("#myform").load(pathtosecondpage, function() {
          //some code after call is completed
          //start to load the data again in 3 seconds
          setTimeout(function(){ loaddata(); }, 3000);
        });

     loaddata();

    });
```